# Return values from nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I'm trying to combine the string values from a nested array to display as a label on a chart.js chart I have. I have used the below code to return part of my data:

```
const data = [
  {
    "TITANIC.AGE_CONTRIBUTION": {
      "(0.419, 14.0)": 0.0764588776,
      "(41.0, 50.0)": -0.0028983768,
      "(14.0, 19.0)": 0.0126423091
    }
  },
  {
    "TITANIC.EMBARKED_CONTRIBUTION": {
      "Q": 0.023986753511113696,
      "C": 0.02789997960547538,
      "S": -0.09335021246545774
    }
  }
];
```

```
const contributions = data
  .flatMap((obj) => Object.values(obj))
  .flatMap((contribution) => Object.entries(contribution));
```

and then passing the below to return (0.419, 14.0) (41.0, 50.0) (14.0, 19.0) and so on:

```
contributions.map((val) => val[0]);
```

What I would like is to diplay the 'title/key' along with val[0], see below.

```
TITANIC.AGE_CONTRIBUTION (0.419, 14.0)
TITANIC.AGE_CONTRIBUTION (41.0, 50.0)
TITANIC.AGE_CONTRIBUTION (14.0, 19.0)
TITANIC.EMBARKED_CONTRIBUTION Q
TITANIC.EMBARKED_CONTRIBUTION C
TITANIC.EMBARKED_CONTRIBUTION S
```

I have tried the below but cant seem to combine the two.

```
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    console.log(value);
  }
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: `data
  .flatMap((i) => Object.entries(i))
  .flatMap((i) => {
    return Object.entries(i[1]).map((j) => {
      return { key: i[0], value: j[0] };
    });
  });
`
do you want this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.flatMap(Object.entries)
  .flatMap(entry => Object.keys(entry[1])
    .map(contribution => entry[0] + " " + contribution)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
const data = [{
    "TITANIC.AGE_CONTRIBUTION": {
      "(0.419, 14.0)": 0.0764588776,
      "(41.0, 50.0)": -0.0028983768,
      "(14.0, 19.0)": 0.0126423091
    }
  },
  {
    "TITANIC.EMBARKED_CONTRIBUTION": {
      "Q": 0.023986753511113696,
      "C": 0.02789997960547538,
      "S": -0.09335021246545774
    }
  }
];

data.forEach((arrayItem) => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(arrayItem)) {
    for (const valueKey of Object.keys(value)) {
      console.log(`${key} ${valueKey}`);
    }
  }
})
```